# How do i grab the dependencies in my bower.json file after i clone the repo?

Tags: dependencies, npm, bitbucket, bower

I have a project set up with bootstrap, bower, grunt, compass, npm, and all that stuff. Everything is working fine and I have it on a repo in Bitbucket.

I've cloned the repo, gotten all the files, but now I cant remember for the life of me how i grab the dependencies from the bower.json file. Im looking to install the "node modules" and "bower components" directories, and the dependencies in them. Im Googling like crazy but all im seeing is stuff on "setting up Bower".

I thought it was 'bower init' but thats not doing it.

Thanks so much guys

Comment: oh ok it is 'bower install' im looking for. I'm having a "Git Tag/branch ~3.2.0+1 does not exist" issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`bower install` will install the dependencies from your `bower.json` file. `bower` follows the same conventions that most CLI applications do, where you can add a `--help` flag to your command to get more information.

```
➜  ~  bower --help
-----------------------------------------
Update available: 1.3.7 (current: 1.2.8)
Run npm update -g bower to update
-----------------------------------------


Usage:

    bower <command> [<args>] [<options>]

Commands:

    cache                   Manage bower cache
    help                    Display help information about Bower
    home                    Opens a package homepage into your favorite browser
    info                    Info of a particular package
    init                    Interactively create a bower.json file
    install                 Install a package locally
    link                    Symlink a package folder
    list                    List local packages
    lookup                  Look up a package URL by name
    prune                   Removes local extraneous packages
    register                Register a package
    search                  Search for a package by name
    update                  Update a local package
    uninstall               Remove a local package

Options:

    -f, --force             Makes various commands more forceful
    -j, --json              Output consumable JSON
    -l, --log-level         What level of logs to report
    -o, --offline           Do not hit the network
    -q, --quiet             Only output important information
    -s, --silent            Do not output anything, besides errors
    -V, --verbose           Makes output more verbose
    --allow-root            Allows running commands as root

See 'bower help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! The problem I was having was a tag/branch issue with 'bootstrap-sass-official' install. I installed it originally using NPM, and got the branch "~3.2.0+1", which was then put into the bower.json file. All was good and I pushed it to a remote on bitbucket.

Now after cloning that remote to another machine, it was time to use 'bower install' to grab bootstrap-sass-official ~3.2.0+1. BUT Bower wasn't seeing that branch. By removing the '+1' in the bower.json file and just saving it as:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.2.0"
  }
```

Bower was able to see and download the dependency.  I hope this helps anyone who has this or a similar problem.